# Bug when sending array in node.js and socket.io

Tags: arrays, serialization, node.js, socket.io

I use socket.io version 0.8.4

I have boiled down my problem to the following. I have data looking like this:

```
data.prop1 = [];
data.prop1.push("man");
data.prop2 = [];
data.prop2["hey"] = "man";
```

I send the data from the server to the client this way:

```
socket.emit("data", data);
```

On the client side I receive the data this way:

```
socket.on("data", function(data){ console.log(data); });
```

The weird thing is:

```
data.prop1 = [];
data.prop1.push("man"); // This data exists in the client side data object
data.prop2 = [];
data.prop2["hey"] = "man"; // This data does not exist.
```

data.prop2 is just an empty array on the client side.

Is there a known bug in json serializing arrays on the form in prop2?

Thankyou in advance

EDIT:

Problem solved using this workaround:

```
data.prop1 = [];
data.prop1.push("man");
data.prop2 = {}; // <= Object instead of array
data.prop2["hey"] = "man";
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

ECMA-262 about `JSON.stringify`:

> The representation of arrays includes only the elements between zero and `array.length – 1` inclusive. Named properties are excluded from the stringification.

Arrays are supposed to have numerical property names. So when the `data.prop2` is transformed to JSON (which socket.io sends the data in, I imagine), it doesn't get the `'hey'` property. If you want to use non-numerical property names, you should use objects instead of arrays:

```js
data.prop1 = [];
data.prop1.push("man");
data.prop2 = {}; // Notice we're creating an object, not an array.
data.prop2["hey"] = "man"; // Alternatively: data.prop2.hey = "man"
```

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, Javascript doesn't really work like that.

Check out [this article](http://blog.xkoder.com/2008/07/10/javascript-associative-arrays-demystified/), about half way down. It explains the problem where you try to set data.prop2["hey"] = "man";